# Read only permission for file on git

Tags: git, chmod, git-push, git-add

I am trying to give permission 400 to a file on git and try to commit the same. But is trying to commit with permssions as " create mode 100644 "

Is it possible to commit file with 400 permissions in git or should I git clone and  handle permission change  in my code

Comment: Do you want to make it so that the remote file cannot be updated, or the local file, or both?

Comment: This is pem file(aws installation) which i want read only permissions checked into git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git supports only one permissions bit: "executable" (`mode 100755`) or "not executable" (`mode 100644`).  This was a deliberate choice—very early Git supported more, and it turned out not to work well.

You will need to chmod the file after checkout, perhaps through one or more hooks.